# TFS2010 Deploy solution two web project

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2010

I am working on solution with 2 web-projects. There is a problem. After building the projects on the test server they should be placed in two different folders and sites IIS. I use TFS2010 to build it and I start buildind with MsBuild arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC 
/p:MSDeployServiceUrl=https://dnx-test:8172/MsDeploy.axd 
/p:DeployIisAppPath="AppPath" 
/p:UserName=domain\username 
/p:Password="password" 
/p:Configuration=QA 
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True.
```

And there is only one project which gets into the right folder (drop folder that configured in build settings).

What should I do to place the second project in another folder?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the second project compiles all together?
First of all take a look at the log and verify both projects compile properly..
Then if they both compile and create their DLL's we need to check configuration differences between them.

Once you give me some more info I'll be able to get a better clue of what's the problem and help you. It could help if you send me the MSBuild's log :)

Oshry